# Display XML nodes in range?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Haven't found this anywhere so I ask it here.
I have a xml document structured as follows:

```
<root>
    <row>Row 1</row>
    <row>Row 2</row>
    <row>Row 3</row>
    <row>Row 4</row>
    <row>Row 5</row>
    <row>Row 6</row>
    <row>Row 7</row>
    <row>Row 8</row>
    <row>Row 9</row>
    <row>Row 10</row>
</root>
```

In a xsl document,I want to display the rows in a range.For example,I want to display only the rows from `Row 3` to `Row 8`,excluding the first and last 2 rows.
I know how to set the limit of the rows but that displays rows starting from `Row 1` (the very first).
Edit:typos

Comment: Please post your attempted XSLT.

Comment: You could use the position() value you you want to use items in loop at specific indexes.

Comment: When you say "from Row 3 to Row 8", do you mean the rows that are 3rd and 8th in the sequence, or the rows whose textual content is "Row 3" / "Row 8" respectively? I'm assuming the content of the rows won't always be as in your example...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates) based on [position](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-position):

```
select="row[position() >= 3 and position() &lt;= 8]"
```

This could be in an `xsl:apply-templates` or in a `xsl:for-each` or even in a `xsl:copy-of` instruction (all from the context of `root`). You didn't post your attempt or the expected result, so we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

To display a specific range of rows in your XML using XSLT, you can utilize the `position()` function along with conditional statements. Here's an example XSLT that displays rows from Row 3 to Row 8:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- Identity template to copy everything as is -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Template to match 'row' elements within a specified range -->
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="row[position() &gt;= 3 and position() &lt;= 8]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Output settings for indentation -->
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[The Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27vG0.png)

Comment: Why repeat (a part of) an answer already given? Also notice that the question is also tagged as HTML, and OP says they "want to display the rows". It's not very likely they just want to copy them "as is". And if that were the case, you could make this much shorter by using `xsl:copy-of` (as also already stated in the other answer).